# Can you play Street Fighter 4 over LAN?

Tags: pc, street-fighter-iv

How to play Street Fighter 4 for PC on LAN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it seems Capcom did the same thing as Blizzard which is not allowing people to LAN their game. However what i found out is that you can use tunneling to make LAN possible. One software for tunneling is `hamachi`.

Here's a video [guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfC_UhY0hoE)

Comment: thx will try it out.